# Azure devops pipelines conditional name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using azure-devops pipelines but I am having problems to set the name of the build.

Here is a normal build definition.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

name: myBuildName

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

What I would like to do is to set the name with a conditional check. If (something) then X otherwise Y

I have checked the [conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=vsts&tabs=yaml) documents, but no luck.

Here is what I would like to do, but obviously does not work

```
# if ReleaseNumber var exists
if ($(ReleaseNumber))
  name: $(ReleaseNumber).$(Build.BuildId)
else
  name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Azure DevOps YAML doesn't support conditions in the values like you tried to do.

The conditional documents you looked is for jobs/tasks execution, you can specify when the task will be executed with a custom condition.

At workaround, you can add a PowerShell task that will update the build name according to your condition.

For example, keep the `$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)` in the name and run this script during the build:

```
if ($env:ReleaseNumber){
  Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$env:ReleaseNumber.$env:Build_BuildId"
  }
else{
  Write-Host "Release Number not exist, build name not changed"
  }
```

Comment: That script that you have, it would be a PowerShell step to update the name, is it?

Comment: Yes, the `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$nameName` is an Azure DevOps method on PowerShell that update the build name.

Comment: Just finished testing your solution. It does work, thank you very much. Although is not practical. This conditional things might be useful not only for the name but for setting variables as well. Would be nice if Microsft adds support for that