# Conditionally include the branch name in an Azure DevOps build name

Tags: azure-devops, expression

I'm using Azure DevOps to build a pipeline, but I wish to change the name of the build. This is entirely possible according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

With that in mind, I tested the following, which worked. So far so good...

```
name: '1.0.$(Rev:r)-$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
```

> 1.0.1-master

However, one of my requirements is to exclude the branch name if it's 'master', so I tried the following. This seemed to work in the first instance, as a 'master' did not have a branch name appended, but when I ran a feature branch I found that `$(Build.SourceBranchName)` was not being expanded.

```
variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    branchName: ''
  ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    branchName: '-$(Build.SourceBranchName)'

name: '1.0.$(Rev:r)$(branchName)'
```

I've since tried `${{ variables.Build.SourceBranchName }}` and `$[variables.Build.SourceBranchName]` as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch), but as written they token is either ignored or returns an empty string. The three formats leave me with the following build names.

> 1.0.1-$(Build.SourceBranchName)
>   1.0.1-
>   1.0.1-$[variables.Build.SourceBranchName]

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) around custom naming makes mention of a variable `$(SourceBranchName)`, but I've tried this and it also fails.

What I find confusing is that the expressions in the `variables:` segment can access the variable values [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#variables), but seemingly the `variables:` segment itself is unable to.

Is it possible to conditionally name the build so that I can include/exclude the branch name as required?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is how you are referencing $(Build.SourceBranchName) in the parse time expression. It is not available in that format under the context. Additional [info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)

This works for me!

```
variables:
  system.debug: true
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    branchName: ''
  ${{ if ne( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    branchName: -${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}

name: '1.0.$(Rev:r)$(branchName)'
```

Some good additional info in Lance's answer `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]` might be a good path, or you could use GitVersion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That does indeed work, although I should point out that it's not documented in the additional info you linked (also referenced in my question). One thing I note about your answer is the lack of quotes - adding them results in an error "can not read an implicit mapping pair".

Comment: @DavidGard you are right it's not very explicit. I am reading a bit between the lines with this page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax

"Variables with macro syntax are processed during runtime....When the system encounters a macro expression, it will replace the expression with the contents of the variable. If there's no variable by that name, then the macro expression is left unchanged. For example, if $(var) cannot be replaced, $(var) won't be replaced by anything."

Comment: My thought is that when you try to use $(Build.SourceBranchName) it is a runtime macro expression used in the context of compile time template expression (your conditional), so at that evaluation context\point in time (compile time), that runtime type macro expression is just not available. Maybe I am over complicating it?

Comment: The other link you referenced that shows the expected format of referencing variables in a conditional is really the pay dirt. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#variables 

But it's not real clear from that page, in your case, that you would have to wrap them in the compile time syntax ${{ <expression> }}.

Comment: I kind of dismissed that initially because the docs seemed to suggest that I couldn't use a expression as the value of a key - happily I can! Hopefully as time goes on MS will clean the docs up a little, as a lot of them for DevOps are really not great!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to conditionally name the build so that I can
>   include/exclude the branch name as required?

An alternative workaround is to use [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to update the build number. Check [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number):

You can use something like: `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]my-new-build-number`.

Example:

```
name: 1.0.$(Rev:r)

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'))
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $buildNumber = $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
      $revision= $buildNumber.Substring($buildNumber.LastIndexOf('.') + 1)
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]1.0.$revision-$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
```

Copy this to your yaml, then it can work to meet your requirements above. About how to use `$(rev:r)` in task, get hint from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213517/10910450), thanks to **Shayki Abramczyk**!

Hope all above helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that I want to do something like this - changing the build name (which surely should be `number` in YAML, given it's unconditionally displayed with a leaded "#" in the UI) should not require a step in the build pipeline.

Comment: Hmm, actually the build number in `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]my-new-build-number` refers to the name in yaml. You can easily check this by running my script in a test project...

Comment: I'm not suggesting that it does not work, just that adding an additional step to change the build name is not something I want to do.